# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) cannot reach to all registered users?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've integrated GCM into my Android app, my app is live with GCM for 3 months already.

I've followed Google's instructions and everything works as expected on my device (Nexus HTC 9 and also on some other devices I tested).

In general, I send a data messages (without the "Notification" key), receive it via the onMessageReceived method, send to my server a ping once the device gets the data and run the code that handles the incoming data (shows a notification for example).

The device gets the data when the app is in foreground, background or even **totally closed (also after restarting the device).**

**But...**

Every 1-2 week I send a data message to all of my users, but I noticed that out of the registration tokens that are still exists, and for the ones that I got a "Success" and "Message Id" from the GCM response, in the end I manage to reach around 50% of the users only (even less in some countries).
If, for example, this is the response:

```
{ "multicast_id": 108,
  "success": 5000,
  "failure": 300,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:08" },
    { "message_id": "1:09" }
...
....
....
...
  ]
}
```

The "success" says 5000, but the onMessageReceived method runs only on 2500 users...

I also looked on FCM diagnostic to check the messages ids status and seems like the devices are getting the messages.

Another test that I did, just to see that my code is good - once the user successfully registered to my server with the registration token that GCM provided me, I immediately push him a "test/dummy" data, just to see that the user gets it and my code is running and send the ping to my server - this "loop" worked for almost 100% of the users...

So how come 1-2 weeks later I cannot reach those users and have a drop from around 100% to 50%...? (I'm talking only for the ones that didn't uninstall my app)

This is what I use in the implementation of GcmListenerService:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        ...
        ...
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        sendPingtoMyServer(context)
    }
}
```

and this is the Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="[MY_PACKAGE].GcmMessageHandler"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="[MY_PACKAGE]" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Topic Messaging and see if the case is also the same? (Although you won't be able to track down messages sent through topics without implementing a *delivery receipt* like function)

Comment: Didn't test it, but as you said, won't be able to track it :) probably will have the same issue. What's weird to me is that If I take the messages ids that didn't ping back to my server, and I check them via the FCM diagnostics tool, the tool shows that the ids successfully delivered to the devices.

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this, and I use node-gmc to send messages, which should not matter since those are api calls.

In my case I send the following parameters

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
   priority: 'high',
   contentAvailable: true,
   content_available: true,
   notification: {
       sound: true,
       title: "StockAlert Notification",
       icon: "ic_launcher",
       body: notification,
   }
 })
```

Anyway, I did have the same issue, playing with the parameters helped.
For some reason **contentAvailable: true** worked on some phones but I had to add **content_available: true**, for others.

I am still looking into this too

Comment: From what I understand, contentAvailable is only for iOS devices, currently I'm talking about Android devices only. also, I'm sending "data" messages and not "notification" messages (sending without the "notification" key, my code inside onMessageReceived gets the data and shows the notification)